# Local SQL vs SQL Azure varchar sorting

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am running this SQL Query on two SQL DBs - one is on my local server ((local).master), and the other is on a SQL Azure server -

```
DECLARE @Res TABLE ([Item] [varchar](100))
INSERT INTO @Res ([Item]) VALUES ('a2-p'),('a-p')
SELECT [Item] FROM @Res ORDER BY [Item]
```

I am getting different results on the DBs -

Local SQL DB result - [image: Local SQL DB Result]

SQL Azure DB result - [image: SQL Azure DB Result]

What is the reason for this behaviour. How can this be corrected?

Comment: Is the collation the same on both servers?

Comment: @Raj How do I see that?

Comment: @CodePro_NotYet: `select collation_name from sys.databases`

Comment: @Raj Yes It was different. Please add it as answer so I can mark it as correct.